# Display multiple rows in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to achieve this:

[image: this]

Instead I am getting similar but NOT the result I'm hoping for:

[image: this]

In thos result that I got from my query, I have rows repeating the SAME thing. For example, if you look at the first 4 results that I highlighted, I want the 1st row to appear and the next 3 to disappear, just like in the first image attached, NO repetition.

I have tried my ways but have got nothing. As in the first image attached, that is the kind of result I am looking for. Kind of nested rows in the last column. Below is what I have tried. I am also attaching a link to my .sql file for ease if anyone can help me with this problem ([link](https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/878202/IjzF6D1BI6VBLTDl/script.sql.txt)). I am using MS SQL.

```
SELECT cj.completed_job_id AS 'Job Card No.', 
       c.cus_name AS 'Customer',
       c.cus_address AS 'Address',
       jt.job_type AS 'Job Type',
       cj.no_of_days AS 'No. of Days',
       CONCAT(jm.mat_quantity, ' ', jm.mat_type) AS 'Materials Used'
FROM completed_jobs cj
JOIN customers c
    ON cj.customer_id = c.customer_id
JOIN job_types jt
    ON cj.job_type = jt.job_type
JOIN job_materials jm
    ON cj.completed_job_id = jm.completed_job_id;
```

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: That looks like a job for your presentation layer, not the RDBMS. Especially with those merged cells and bullet points.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all of columns without "material used" and make subquery that contains only "material used" for that row.
In that subquery you can convert result to xml to put results into one cell and in next step replace xml tags.

Not very elegant but working - part of SQL below:

```
SELECT cj.completed_job_id AS 'Job Card No.', 
       c.cus_name AS 'Customer',
       c.cus_address AS 'Address',
       jt.job_type AS 'Job Type',
       cj.no_of_days AS 'No. of Days',
       (SELECT CONCAT(jm.mat_quantity, ' ', jm.mat_type) as material FROM job_materials jm WHERE cj.completed_job_id = jm.completed_job_id FOR XML AUTO) AS 'Materials Used'
FROM completed_jobs cj
JOIN customers c
    ON cj.customer_id = c.customer_id
JOIN job_types jt
    ON cj.job_type = jt.job_type
```

Comment: Tried. I am getting this error :- Msg 6809, Level 16, State 1, Line 144
-> Unnamed tables cannot be used as XML identifiers as well as unnamed columns cannot be used for attribute names. Name unnamed columns/tables using AS in the SELECT statement.

Comment: I have not any mssql database already. Try to name concat column as below:
(SELECT CONCAT(jm.mat_quantity, ' ', jm.mat_type) as material FROM job_materials jm WHERE cj.completed_job_id = jm.completed_job_id FOR XML AUTO) AS 'Materials Used'